# Find and replace Subscript tabs with subscripts in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, replace, find, subscript

I want to make my Macro do a find and replace on a large data set replacing all of the subscript tabs with the actual subscript.

So `A<SUB>2</SUB>` would become `A₂` etc etc...

I was able to mimic this for Superscripts easy enough as the superscript characters can be shown in excel but when I tried to record a macro for subscripts it just spat out a regular 2, not the 2 as subscript.

I tried to see if there was an ASCII or unicode codes for them, but I couldn't find those either.

Comment: Hmm. The macro recorder works well for me. Relevant code snippet:     `With ActiveCell.Characters(Start:=2, Length:=1).Font`, `.Subscript = True`.

Comment: That looks like it's going to replace a particular character position, rather than the character itself?  When I tried it I got this  ```'''Selection.Replace What:="<SUB>2</SUB> ", Replacement:="2", LookAt:=xlPart _
        , SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False'''```

Comment: I guess I assumed you were looping instead of find/replace.

Comment: I used a loop for a similar macro, but this is a different requirement and a loop won't work  here.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>The macro recorder does work here for me:</strike>

```
With Application.ReplaceFormat.Font
    .Strikethrough = False
    .Superscript = False
    .Subscript = True
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
Cells.Replace What:="<SUB>2</SUB>", Replacement:="2", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=True
```

**EDIT**:

Seems like you need to loop, something like this. Could probably be optimized to not loop over all the cells in the used range, but it was still pretty fast in testing:

```vb
Sub Foo()
    Dim rng As Range
    For Each rng In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        If TypeName(rng.Value) = "String" Then
            Dim position As Long
            position = InStr(rng.Value, "<SUB>2</SUB>")
            
            Dim length As Long
            length = Len("<SUB>2</SUB>")
            
            If position > 0 Then
                rng.Characters(position, length).Text = "2"
                rng.Characters(position, 1).Font.Subscript = True
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks again BigBen! I'm not sure  what you did to get a different result when you recorded the macro but this works perfectly!

Comment: Ah no, In testing I find this converts the whole cell to subscript, not just the numbers...